# React const in alert box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert

So I want to have a `alert()` Box. I have a `const` (`Math.round(Math.random() * 10000000)`) and now I want to get this random number in my alert box. I just wrote that:

```
    const handleClick = () => {
        alert({random})
    }
```

But instead of getting e.g. 8 I get `[Object object]`
How to get e.g. 8 or 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are wrapping it in an object

```js
const handleClick = () => { 
alert(random)
 }
```